# Trouble understanding some terms that have to do with undirected graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-traversal, undirected-graph

this is an example problem from an old midterm:

Let G = (V, E) be a connected undirected graph where the edges have positive integer edge weights associated with them, and a vertex s ∈ V is the source. Provide an algorithm that for each vertex t ∈ V reports the minimum last edge weight on a non-decreasing path from s to t (∞ if there is no such path). A path v1, v2, . . . vr is non-decreasing if w(v_i, v_i+1) ≤ w(v_i+1, v_i+2) for i = 1, 2, ...r−2.

Am I correct in thinking that the problem wants me to come up with an algorithm that given a graph with a starting vertex, can find the length of the shortest path, that also has edge weights increasing as you go down the path, to every other vertex it can reach?

Comment: Not the path length. The minimum last edge weight.

Comment: what is the last minimum edge weight? just the weight of the last edge?

Comment: alright, that was one of the more confusing terms, thanks!

Comment: To be clear. From all non-decreasing paths that and at any `t`, you are supposed to pick the path with the minimum last edge weight.

Comment: @Nico yes that is completely correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to write an algorithm that provides a path from the source vertex `s` to a (can be any) vertex `t` where the weights of the path between `s` and `t` increase (or stay the same). It then asks to get the minimum weight of the last edge of all these possible paths.

In other words, you need to see which path from `s` to `t` (which should be non-decreasing in weights) gives the lowest weight in the last edge.

Comment: so if I was to find all possible paths from s to t that increase, then report the path out of those that has the lowest weight in the last edge. that would give a correct (and slow) result, right?